# Change wlclient in mobilefirst platform dynamically in android real device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I followed a post on https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/ . It works fine on emulators but when i tried it on real android device it failed. The Url changed but it cannot connect to the server. I can't understand what is the issue.
Can i have some help please.
 Thank you.

**Logcat**
[Click here to view the logcat](http://mfpreader.comze.com/logcat.html)

Comment: Provide your LogCat log.

Comment: it is on an real device.

Comment: So what? Connect your device with a USB cable and observe LogCat. You will see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Update: as can be seen in the uploaded LogCat:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.3 (port 10080) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

10.0.0.3 is an internal IP address and will not be available to your device; change the IP address to the "real", public, IP address of your machine.

======

The only reason for the API to fail, is if the remote server does not have the .wlapp file of the application deployed to it, or if you are pointing to a non-existing server.

If the .wlapp file is deployed, then you need to provide the LogCat log from the time of the error.

Comment: i tried putting the "real", public, IP address of your machine even though failed to connect. :(

Comment: Logcat shows - Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /196.20.240.220 (port 10080) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
a) Verify host and port is correct
b) To verify connectivity, try accessing the MFP operations console from the browser on your device .

Comment: I think the problem is that even if the value is changed, the recompilation of the file is not performed well. The https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/ does not work on real device.it works only in simulators because it within the nvironment

Comment: Can you start packet capture while running your android port scanner app (we can check what is going on on the network) with filter: ip.addr=10.0.0.3

Comment: it can be either network issue (firewall / iptables) or FTP issue

Comment: Works in emulator not on real device - this points to an obvious network issue. Like Nazmul Hasan suggested, check your network settings. A wirecapture will tell you if the request is reaching the server. Also, have you tried accessing the operations console from the real device? If that also does not work, then clearly a network issue

Comment: Latest updated logcat: mfpreader.comze.com/logcat3.html. I think this will help us find the solution